How remove icons of folder or file when i Drop in Tauti
I'm creating a Tauri app, but when I try to drop any file or folder, works fine in logic, but in the desktop the icons of this elements never despair, how I solve that because is very annoying. I attached a image for more description of the problem:
UPDATE
I use linux-manjaro with file explorer nautilus and I change with other file explorer like dolphin and this error never happened 



Tauri does not show you an icon when you use drag and drop functionality.
So this icons are most likely are shown inside your JavaScript library you're using to facilitate the file drag and drop functionality.
Share your minimal reproducible source code and OS, so we can all take a closer look.
